# I am trying to delete a record from grid view but unable to delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to delete a record from grid view but unable to delete.
Getting Error like this while delete a record from gridview using link button in template field.

```
    var id = GvTestimony.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Error message is here:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

```
void TestimoniesGrid()
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_conn))
    {
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_TestimoniesGridData", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    GvTestimony.EmptyDataText = "This table has no data.";
                }
                else
                {
                    GvTestimony.DataSource = dataTable;
                    GvTestimony.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void lnkReject_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var linkButton = sender as LinkButton;
    if (linkButton != null)
    {
        var gvRow = linkButton.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        var id = GvTestimony.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_conn))
        {
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_DeleteTestimonyById", sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnStoryId", id);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                var result = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection.Close();
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    TestimoniesGrid();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before deleting on server side bind it again.

Comment: yes i did. am bind to display records in grid in page load

Comment: whats inside `SP_DeleteTestimonyById` ?

Comment: @OwnStoryId int=0
As
Begin
 DELETE FROM [OwnStory] WHERE [OwnStoryId]=@OwnStoryId
End

Comment: Show the code of `TestimoniesGrid`.

Comment: where are you calling the function `TestimoniesGrid()` other than `if (result == 1) { TestimoniesGrid(); }`  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(sorry it´s my first answer) Could be interesting to see how are you defining the Grid Columns, and which version of .NET are you using.

Here you can find an example with a Button:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/get-gridview-rowindex-upon-button-click

I am going to copy the most important part, you can do it in two different ways:

- Get GridView Row and GridView Row Index on RowCommand Event

  `protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[index]; 
  }`
- Get GridView Row and GridView Row Index on Click Event of Button in TemplateField

  `protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
      int index = gvRow.RowIndex;
  }`

If you need more information please let me know.

More examples:

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: I cannot understand why my answer is "down voted", The problem it´s related with this line `var id = GvTestimony.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();`. And I am sure that it´s related by the definition. The problem it´s not related with the Store PRocedures... it´s because the id it´s null. And in my links you can see how it´s possible to delete a row.